# mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/fundavnzla/index.php on line 158

Tags: php, html5, mysqli, phpmyadmin

El siguiente es un simple formalario con dos inputs, nombre y comentario. Deseo imprimir esos dos campos en una tabla, pero al momento de ejecutar me sale error. la coneccion con la base de dato esta bien.

> mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given
>    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/fundavnzla/index.php on line 158

Expongo mi codigo para que lo analizen y puedan ver en que estoy errando
Formulario:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nombre"  class="sr-only">Nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="comentario"  class="sr-only"></label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comentario" name="comentario" placeholder="Deja tu comentario..."></textarea>  
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showValue()" type="button">Enviar</button>
              </form>
```

tengo el llamado del conexion.php al inicio del index

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
?>
```

ahora deseo consultar en una tabla los resultados, para ello uso :

```
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">          
        <?php
        $sql="select * form comentarios";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);           
        ?>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>nombre</td>
                    <td>comentario</td>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($resultado))

                     {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['comentario']; }?></td>
                    </tr> 
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

La linea que me resalta error es :

```
<?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($resultado))
```

Comment: En tu consulta pones `form` en vez de `FROM`, cambialo y comenta que sucede.

Comment: si, era ese era el error, muchas Gracias estaba asi toda la mañana.

Comment: Suele suceder. por lo general cuando te sale ese tipo de error es porque tu consulta tiene algo que no esta especificado en la BD por ejemplo campos o tablas o en este caso escribir mal la clausula FROM.